# Most efficient order to reduce like elements in multiple arrays so the array has 0 elements

Tags: arrays

Can someone please assist in how I would solve this problem; I need to figure out a way to eliminate like elements in multiple arrays in the best/quickest order in order to drive my array to 0 elements. I.E. if I had the following arrays:

```
         'a    {1,12,10,31}'
         'b    {12,21}'
         'c    {12,18,5,21}'
         'd    {12,18,21}'
```

I'd want to remove 12 -> 21 (b is done) then -> 18 (d is done)

This problem is really related to software incompatibilities... Any ideas would be helpful.
Thanks,
Pat

Comment: What are you removing elements based on? E.g. If you just set the length of all of them to zero that would be quickest but likely not do what you need.

Comment: Its removing integers found in more than 1 array and keeping integers found in only 1 array

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on how many is multiple arrays. If you only have two, you can sort them individually, and iterate over both at the same time in order, and remove.

However, this gets complicated quickly when you have an arbitrary number of arrays.

In this case, it is easiest to:

1. Put everything (merge) in a single array (named ARRAY)
2. Sort the array (ARRAY)
3. Iterate over the array (ARRAY), while removing elements occurring just once, and leaving a single copy of elements occurring multiple times
4. Then for each original array (eg. A, B, C, D), iterate over this original array (eg. A) along with ARRAY together, and remove elements in A that are also found in ARRAY.

For step 4., you probably want something like (written in pseudo-C code):

```
foreach (A = arrays [A, B, C, D]) { // for each original array
  int j=0;
  for (int i=0;i<A.size;i++) { // iterating over array A
    // increase index j to iterate ARRAY (find closest # in ARRAY >= A[i])
    while (j<ARRAY.size-1 && A[i]>ARRAY[j]) j++;

    if (ARRAY[j]==A[i]) /* remove it */;
    else /* keep it */;
  }
}
```